# ValueError: unconverted data remains: .000397

Tags: python

I have date which looks like "2012-11-02 21:00:20.000397",am running into following error with the code below...can anyone provide inputs on what is wrong?

CODE:-

```
create_date = datetime.strptime(str(CRItem['CR Created Date']), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
CR_created_date = "{}/{}/{}".format(create_date.month,d.day,d.year)
CRMailBody = CRMailBody + "<tr>"
```

ERROR:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 482, in <module>
    create_date = datetime.strptime(str(CRItem['CR Created Date']), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\_strptime.py", line 328, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: .000397
```

Comment: Sounds like strptime doesn't like microseconds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your format string doesn't ever deal with those extra microseconds.

Unfortunately, [strftime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html?highlight=strptime#time.strftime) does not handle microseconds, so you'll want to remove the extra characters (`.000397`) with a regex or by use of a properly crafted substring call.

For example, use:

```
create_date = datetime.strptime(str(CRItem['CR Created Date']).split(".")[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: @hexafraction..any inputs on how to fix it?

Comment: @user2125827 Read last sentence.

Comment: i mean any inputs what sort of regex touse? regex might be an overkill here..any other smart way

Comment: You might use `my_str.split(".")[0]`.

Comment: @WaleedKhan -     create_date = datetime.strptime(str(CRItem['CR Created Date'].split(".")[0]), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: @does anybody have any inputs?

Comment: @user2125827 `create_date = datetime.strptime(str(CRItem['CR Created Date']).split(".")[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

Comment: @hexafraction - i already tried that..am getting the error AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: @user2125827 I moved a parentheses over.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing your format string to

```
'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'
```

Other directives for format strings can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)